# Starts with selector

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use the 'starts with' selector inside my Sass program, but for some reason I got an error.

I have the following code:

```
a[href=^="//youtube.com"]
    color: red
```

This throws the following error:

`Invalid CSS after "a[href=": expected identifier or string, was "^="//youtube.com"]"`

How can I resolve this error?

My Ruby version is:

`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]`

To compile my SASS code to CSS I use `Grunt` with `grunt-contrib-sass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `a[href^="//youtube.com"]`

Comment: Oh, I'm ashamed. For some reason I didn't saw that I have two '=' in my selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's a standard CSS selector (an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) rather than a SASS feature but you got the syntax wrong:

> `[attr^=value]`
>       Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.